# add jQuery webcam plugin to wordpress site

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add a jquery plugin to my wordpress site. the plugin is: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

I activated jquery in my functions.php
added the script to my files

like this:

```
function webcam_script() {

wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_register_script('jquery', 'http' . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 's' : '') . 
'://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js', false, null, true);

wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_register_script('my-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.webcam.js', false, 
null, true);

wp_enqueue_script('my-js');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'webcam_script');
```

but this plugin doesn't give me a lot of information on how to activate it. And putting it in wordpress is making me even more confused. I want the webcam to be on the homepage (video page)

here is a link to my site:

http://i-am-here.net/wordpress/

Comment: first thing is you dont require to register jquery as its built in in wordpress see `wp_enqueue_script` on codex. then check in console area for js errors.

Comment: Even more, it is recommended that we **do not deregister** the bundled jQ WP version. . . . . I've checked the plugin page and there`s *lots of information* on how to activate the plugin. You're not showing any code related to that. Where's your **`$("#camera").webcam({})`**?

Comment: I have no idea where to begin when trying to implement this to a wordpress site.

Comment: I put the js files in my theme js fold then added a div that is named the same as the jQuery webcam example I found in the page source on the page I want in wordpress. But nothing happens